# UploadCollection instantUpload="false" when Embedded in List

Tags: sapui5

I am using `sap.m.UploadCollection` to manage files selected by the user and upload to the server. I want the user to select all the required files then press a 'Save' button to upload all the files at one time. Thus I have set `instantUpload` to `false`. This `UploadCollection` is a part of the items in a `sap.m.List`. When the user selects a file from the file system an upload is automatically performed (not desired). If I use the same `UploadCollection` definition outside of the `List` it does not upload immediately. I need to get it working properly inside the list.

Code Snippet:

```
<List
    items="{ path: 'submittal>/submission', templateShareable: true }">
    <layoutData>
        <layout:GridData span="XL12 L12 M12 S12"/>
    </layoutData>
    <items>
        <CustomListItem>
            <Panel headerText="Round # {submittal>roundId}" expandable="true" expanded="true">
                <forms:SimpleForm layout="ResponsiveGridLayout" editable="true">
                    <UploadCollection
                        noDataText="No documents on file"
                        items="{path : 'submittal>documents', templateShareable : false}"
                        mode="SingleSelectMaster"
                        uploadEnabled="true"
                        uploadButtonInvisible="false"           
                        uploadUrl="OptionController?optionId=JS002&#38;action=submittalUpload"
                        instantUpload="false"
                        multiple="true"
                        beforeUploadStarts="submittalBeforeUpload"
                        uploadComplete="submittalUploadComplete"
                        selectionChange="documentSelected">
                        <layoutData>
                            <layout:GridData span="XL6 L8 M10 S12" linebreakXL="true" linebreakL="true" linebreakM="true" linebreakS="true" />
                        </layoutData>
                        <items>
                            <UploadCollectionItem
                                documentId="{submittal>id}"
                                fileName="{submittal>name}"
                                mimeType="{submittal>typeName}"
                                selected="{submittal>selected}"
                                visibleEdit="false"
                                enableDelete="true"
                                deletePress="documentDelete">
                                <attributes>
                                    <ObjectAttribute title="File size" text="{ path: 'submittal>size', formatter: '.formatFileSize' }" />
                                </attributes>
                            </UploadCollectionItem>
                        </items>
                    </UploadCollection>
                 </forms:SimpleForm>
            </Panel>
        </CustomListItem>
    </items>
</List>
```

UI5 Version: 1.78.1

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is **not** recommended to use *UploadCollection* directly inside *List, Table*, etc. but there is a simple workaround.

Just put a *sap.m.Button* into *sap.m.List* instead of using directly *sap.m.UploadCollection*. Then define *fragment* with a *sap.m.Dialog* that has *sap.m.UploadCollection* inside. In a button press event callback you just bind a row context into a dialog so you'll be able to show correct uploaded files (if there are any).

You can also design a button in your list in a way that you use attachment icon as an icon property and a number (counter) in a text property indicating how many files have been already uploaded.

It would be confusing for an end user to see list items and then another items (files) from UploadCollection inside one or more list items..

Comment: Hmmm. Interesting idea. I may just give that a try as it would be a much cleaner look as well. Thank you.